# iCustom() buffer - how to get values from Custom Indicator buffers in MT4?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I am trying to write an EA that will place a BUY, when the Custom Indicator shows an arrow { sell or buy }. I am using an **`iCustom()`** to do that, but I am struggling with comparing values.

Here is my code:

```html
void OnTick()
  {
//---
       double sell=iCustom(NULL,0,"fx30",0,0);
       double buy=iCustom(NULL,0,"fx30",1,0);
       
       if(sell>0)//sell
       {
        //check if buy trade is running
        //close a buy trade
        //open a sell trade on success
         if(buyTicket>0)
          {
            bool ret=OrderClose(buyTicket, lot, Bid, slipage,clrBlue);
            if(ret==true)
              {
                printf("the sell number is: "+sell);
                sellTicket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,lot,Bid,slipage,NULL,NULL,"MATHUNYA SELL",magic,0,clrRed);
              }
          }
         else
         {
           //we dont have a buy trade open
           //place a sell trade
           //only one trade should be open
           if(sellTicket>0)
           {
             printf("sell order already running");
           }
           else
           {
             printf("the sell number is: "+sell);
             sellTicket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,lot,Bid,slipage,NULL,NULL,"MATHUNYA SELL",magic,0,clrRed);
           }     
         }            
       }
       else{
         Print("buy: "+buy+", sell: "+sell+" Time: "+TimeToStr(Time[1]));
         printf("awaiting sell order..");
       }
       
       if(buy>0)//buy
       {
       //check if sell trade is running
       //close a sell trade
       //open a buy trade on success
         if(sellTicket>0)
          {
            bool ret=OrderClose(sellTicket, lot, Ask, slipage,clrYellow);
            if(ret==true)
              {
                printf("the buy number is: "+buy);
                buyTicket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,lot,Ask,slipage,NULL,NULL,"MATHUNYA BUY",magic,0,clrGreen);
              }
          }
         else
         {
           //we dont have a sell trade open
           //place a buy trade
           //only one trade should be open
           if(buyTicket>0)
           {
             printf("buy order already running");
           }
           else
           {
              printf("the buy number is: "+buy);
              buyTicket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,lot,Ask,slipage,NULL,NULL,"MATHUNYA BUY",magic,0,clrGreen);
           }     
         }          
       }else
       {
         Print("buy: "+buy+", sell: "+sell+" Time: "+TimeToStr(Time[1]));
         printf("awaiting buy order..");
       }
      
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
// global variables

int    buyTicket  =   0;
int    sellTicket =   0;
double lot        =   0.01;
int    slipage    =   3;
int    magic      = 321;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by comparing values? as I can see, you only compare `sell>0` and `buy>0`. My advice: immediately below that comparing add line
`Print(__LINE__," indicator value = "+DoubleToStr(sell,Digits));`
and same with `buy`. It is likely, but of course we do not have crystal ball here, that your indicator returns value (e.g. 100 or 1.16000) on one buffer, and `EMPTY_VALUE` on another. EMPTY_VALUE is 2^31-1 in mql4 so it is larger then zero. 
if you will see that indicator value is 2147483648.00000 or something like that, - you need to replace `sell > 0` with `sell != EMPTY_VALUE` or combine.